# Add plist dictionary to favourites tab (TableView), using XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, plist, favorites

I use a plist containing of an array of dictionaries to fill a MainTableViewController through a MutableArray. When a cell is chosen, the reprecented dictionary are passed to the DetailViewController, where the values from the strings in the reprecented dictionary are displayed. I've added a button to the DetailView in the storyboard, and I want this button to send the reprecented dictionary to the Favorites tab, which is called FavoritesTableViewController. I'm thinking of ways to do it but I'm new to programming so I have to ask for advice.

I've come up with two possible ways of doing it.  I may be far away from the right answer, but at least I'm trying to think.

1: The button changes a boolean to yes in the reprecented dictionary, and the prototype cell in the FavoritesViewController are told to display the dictionaries with boolean=yes.

2: The button copies the dictionary to a new plist with favourites, displayed in the favourites tableview.

But I really have no idea..

EDIT:

Code so far in the DetailViewController:

```
-(IBAction)FavoriteButton:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ItemSelected"
                                                    object:selectedObject];


}
```

Code so far to display the wines in the FavoritesViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"ItemSelected"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notif) {
                                                  [favoritedObjects release];
                                                  favoritedObjects = [[notif object] retain];
                                                  [self.tableView reloadData];
                                              }];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [favoritedObjects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Favcell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

    NSString *cellValue = [favoritedObjects valueForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.textlabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

This shows 20 cells with the value from the Key: "Name" from the last Object in the DetailViewController I pressed "Add to Favorites" button for. For example if I add "Gato Negro" to favorites, it displays "Gato Negro" in 20 cells. if I then add "Luna" to fav, it displays "Luna" in the 20 cells in FavoritesViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about posting a notification and passing the selected dictionary as the `object` or `userInfo`?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ItemSelected"
                                                    object:mySelectedDictionary];
```

In the `FavoritesViewController` you just subscribe to this notification (e.g. in the `init` method) like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"ItemSelected"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notif) {
                                                  [dictionaryToShow release];
                                                  dictionaryToShow = [[notif object] retain];
                                                  [self.tableView reloadData];
                                              }];
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I declare dictionaryToShow?

Comment: In DetailViewcontroller, for mySelectedDictionary, I wrote the identifier for the string carrying the dictionary from the MainTableViewController. But in FavoritesViewController how do I declare dictionaryToShow? to reprecent the selected objects?

Comment: I suppose it should just be an `NSDictionary` declared as member variable in your `DetailViewController`.

Comment: Ok got that, but will you take a look at the edit in my question?

Comment: You should somehow transform your `favoritedObjects` dictionary into an `NSArray`. Table views are index-based while dictionaries operate with keys. Although you can access the dictionary items (see `allValues` and `allKeys`), there is no guarantee that they are always returned in the same order, neither that the order of values match the order of keys. So if I were you, I'd enumerate the key-value pairs in the notification handler and store and feed those into the table instead.